# What exactly is a DNA molecule?

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics

Are the two strands of the double helix collectively called the DNA molecule, or is each individual strand the DNA molecule?

Comment: Been asked before. Try searching to find it. But you won’t find a satisfactory answer, because it’s not a question that concerns molecular biologists. Semantics are not where science is at in the 21st century.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a DNA molecule a single strand of polynucleotide or two of them linked together?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66343/is-a-dna-molecule-a-single-strand-of-polynucleotide-or-two-of-them-linked-togeth)

Comment: @Dirigible Kinda. There doesn't seem to be agreement between the answers posted by different users on that post, though one of the users posted a reference from a book, so I'm going with that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @David I found the post, thanks. As you said, no satisfactory answer. Yeah, modern science isn't too concerned with the semantics of stuff, and rightly so, but sometimes there are loose definitions of some things that do confuse me sometimes while reading course material.

Comment: I have actually added an answer to that post as the accepted answer is, in my opinion, an unjustified assertion. There is, as far as I am aware, no formal definition of molecule in a molecular biological context — presumably because there is no need for one.